# Show wishlist counter on header when it doesnt have items

Tags: static-block, wishlist, header, cms-block, items

I need to display cart and wishlist counters on my own header block. For the first one i've just modified the CSS to display block.
[image]

But I can't find how the wish list counter works, so it will show 0 when it has no items.
[image]

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: can you please some more details